# Ruby .gsub how to shorten a line of code that makes similar substitutions

Tags: ruby, string, gsub

I have a line of Ruby code that looks something like this:

```
words = params[:words].gsub("\n","").gsub("\s","")
```

Is there a better way to do this since the code takes all spaces and newlines and gets rid of them? Just curious if there is a better or shorter way, in the case that I'm being too repetitive in my code.

The above code ***does*** work for me, but I'm new to programming and want to do things the better/more aesthetic way if possible.

Comment: If the whitespace you want to remove is at the beginning or end of the string, which is the common case in rails, then `.strip` will do it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
words = params[:words].delete("\s\n")
```

Comment: right. also using `delete` should be much faster than `gsub`.

Comment: '\s' is supposed to include newline

Comment: @kurumi: this is not a regexp, \s just matches a space.

Answer (score 5):

actually, using only `\s` to match any whitespace character should work:

```
"some\n simple  demo \nstring \n".gsub(/\s/, "")  # => "somesimpledemostring"
```